# Why do I have two kinds of pubic hair?

Tags: human-anatomy, human-evolution

I feel silly even asking this question, but there's a quirk of my anatomy that I find interesting, and I can find nothing about it online.  I am looking for information on whether this quirk is documented, and whether it has any biological role.

I am a Caucasian male, and my quirk is that I have two different kinds of pubic hair.  On my genitals and immediately above, I have a dark wiry kind of hair like that which I find under my armpits and on my chest.  Above this, there is a second bundle of hair which is fairer (similar color to the hair on my head) and curlier.  The color difference between the two hair types is marked.  There is also a small amount of hair continuing up to my navel, which appears to be of the first type (same as chest, armpits, and genitals).

So my questions are:

1. Is this a common feature?
2. If not, is it documented at all?
3. Does it serve a biological purpose?

My reason for asking 3, in particular, is that I've heard multiple explanations for the existence of pubic hair.  One theory is that it indicates sexual maturity.  Another is that it is related to hygiene.  My anatomy seems to suggest both might be true: Hair under armpits is presumably for some practical purpose, like wicking sweat out of an otherwise dank crevice, and the hair on the genitals would appear to have the same effect.  On the contrary, colored hair like that on the head is presumably a secondary sexual characteristic, and the fact that I have a bunch of colored pubic hair above my genitals (where there is no apparent practical purpose, as with the hair below) would seem to serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Relatively interesting evolution question --- hypothesis regarding reasons for certain evolutionary traits can be debated (this particular question, scientists seem to have many theories). However, here is one possible explanation:

1. Pubic hair near the sexual organs is likely for hygiene function; especially for women infections from parasites were common in those areas. The hair would act as a protection barrier, and hence the different texture of that hair being a little thicker.
2. Pubic hair in arm pit regions may keep pheromones, or chemicals your body produces that send subconscious messages to other humans. Often, these chemicals are released from sweat, and hence it would make sense to have hair in those regions to trap them there. The texture of the hair in those regions probably evolved to be more effective in keeping oder.

https://www.self.com/story/why-you-have-pubic-hair
https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/bering-in-mind/a-bushel-of-facts-about-the-uniqueness-of-human-pubic-hair/

Answer (score 0):

what you are describing the the difference between [terminal hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_hair) the coarsed darker hair an [vellus hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vellus_hair) the fine hair. Yes all adults have both. 
 Vellus hair covers basically your entire body, Terminal hair mostly develops during puberty as a secondary sexual characteristic and only covers certain areas. the function of terminal hair and pubic hair is hotly debated and may differ from area to area. Proposed functions include friction/chafing prevention (armpits), scent retention, or even just as a maturity signal.